# Possibility for same Private Key Generation in identity-based encryption

Tags: identity-based-encryption

In private key generation of IBE scheme, private key is generated as follows: $SK_{ID}=s.H(ID)$
 
Suppose two servers use the same curve domain parameters.
If PKG on server A generates private key $SK_{ID}=s.H(ID)$
PKG on server B generates private key $SK_{ID}=b.H(ID)$
for the same ID.
If there are more than 100000 servers, will there be possibility for generating same private key?

Comment: Just two servers are enough to have a "possibility" of identical keys.

Comment: fkraiem. Please explain it to me.

Comment: Well, what if $s = b$?

Comment: The probability for s=b is high or low?

Comment: I do not know what it mean for a probability to be "hard" or "easy".

Comment: If so, in real applications,  if two servers  use the same domain curve parameters, is the security  weak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $s$ and $b$ are the main master secret key components of two IBE servers.

If $s=b$, then $SK_{ID,s}=SK_{ID,b}$ provided that the curve parameters and the hash function $H$ are the same. Now, the question is what's the probability of two IBE servers generating the same master secret key components. This depends on the actual scheme and the field it is defined over.

In IBE, mostly pairing-based groups are used. We usually have $s,b\in \mathbb{Z}_{r}$ where the curve is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$. For example, $r$ is set to be a solinas prime for Type A pairing in PBC. The default values for Type A pairing are $|q|=512$ and $|r|=160$. So, the probability of at least two of $n$ servers generating the same master secret key is essentially the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and can be computed as such:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p(n) & = & 1 - \frac{r!}{r^n\left(r-n\right)!}\\
& = & 1 - \frac{\prod^r_{i=r-n+1}i}{r^n}\\
& = & 1 - \prod^r_{i=r-n+1}\frac{i}{r}
\end{eqnarray}$$

The probability is roughly $3\cdot 10^{-39}$ in your case. [Here's the groovy script](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/9320b8c91e30b78e3706408e023d61a1) I calculated it with. The result is $3\cdot 10^{-42}$ under the assumption that $|r|=170$.

Comment: ArtjomB. Can that probability cause weak security?

Comment: The simpler approximation $p(n)\approx{n(n-1)\over2r}$ also gives $\approx3\cdot 10^{-42}$. This is negligibly low compared to the risk of destruction of human life on earth by a comet during the forthcoming year (which is considerably more than $10^{-9}$). It would follow that the short answer is: no, there is no practical risk that well-behaving IBE servers accidentally generate the same master secret key components.

Comment: @LaYateMay No, it's incredibly unlikely to generate the same parameters. If you have doubt, then require that every IBE server generates their own curve parameters.

Comment: fgrieu. What about the case of IBE servers that are not well-behaving? In such cases, security risk?

Comment: @LaYateMay If the servers are not well-behaving all bets are off. They can do anything they want including talking to each other and co-ordinate the same MSK generation.

Comment: Artjom B. Can you please explain calculating the probability? I can't get that answer. $3.10^{-42}$. Suppose server 2 wants to try to get the same master secret key with server 1 without notice of server 1.  First, it will get private key corresponding to ID1 from server 1. And then, it may try repeatedly to get the same private key using ID1. Is it easy or not?

Comment: @LaYateMay Do you mean why the groovy script is doing another calculation than the Birthday probability formula? Since $r$ is already quite large, calculating $2^{170}!$ would simply not be possible, therefore it is necessary to match the factorial factors in numerator and denominator, because most of them cancel each other out.

Comment: Artjom B. why $2^{170}!$ ? In the formula described above, just $r$! I wanna know substituted value in p(n) formula.

Comment: Yes, the formula says $r!$ and I also said that $|r|\approx 170$ which means that $r\approx 2^{170}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41038/discussion-between-la-yate-may-and-artjom-b).